# Trace Android Application Using USB Trace

Tags: android, usb

There are so many USB tracing application on the internet is there any USB tracing application that can trace only one application that is being installed in an Android Powered device. In short communication between PC and application installed in an android powered device.

Comment: Applications installed on an android device *do not normally communicate* with a PC over a USB cable.  So your first step is going to be to figure out if yours really does, and if so by what means.  Once you identify the means, you can look at interception.  It's quite likely anything going on would be socket based, so you could try interception at the network stack layer, likely on the PC rather than the Android device since you are more likely to be able to get superuser/administrator permission there.  Since such communication is rare, identifying that of interest shouldn't be hard.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are looking for Logcat

http://developer.android.com/tools/help/logcat.html

Comment: Sorry for adding trace in my question, actually am not lookin for LogCat, what i need is any communication between application installed in android device and PC is displayed in an application which is in PC, searched the net and found Multi Port terminal and USB Analyzer but they give details related to android device as a whole i just want it for one application.